# Mirror text in a file and write it to another file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How do I read from a file and write every sentenence to a different file. But every line has to be reversed and centered. Something seems to be wrong with the `#write mirror file` part

```
#some variables
Lines = 0
ShortestLine = 80
Longestline = 0
Emptylines = 0
width = 80
Fillchar = " "

#open files
file = "radishsurvey.txt"
p = open (file,"r")
q = open ("mirroredfile.txt","w")

#loop to count lines and length
for line in p:
    Lines +=1
    length = len(line)
    if length < ShortestLine:
        ShortestLine = length
    if length > Longestline:
        Longestline = length
    if length == 0:
        Emptylines += 1

#write mirror file
    q.write("{0:}\n".format(p.reversedString(line[-2::-1]).center(80)))

q.close()
p.close()
```

The error i get when running this code is

```
line 40, in <module>
    q.write("{0:}\n".format(p.reversedString(line[-2::-1]).center(80)))
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'reversedString'
```

Comment: So it seems you get an error when running the code. Please read [mcve]. Show such a [mcve] including the full error traceback you get.

Comment: @importanceOfBeingErnest ok I edited it now

Answer (score 0):

"W" clean your file first, then write your new data! you should append your file, use "a" for save your previous data ...

Comment: I know this already. But this problem is about the error I get,:

AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'reversedString